# React Native ListView scrollToEnd it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I use the ListView's `scrollToEnd`, but it doesn't work, but it worked for `scrollTo`. What should I do to deal with it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this would work since the ListView doesn't have to render all elements when the view is mounted. There's also no way of knowing when the ListView is done with rendering all the elements. AFAIK the `scrollToEnd` method can be used with a button.

Comment: Are you getting an error or is it just not doing anything?

Comment: Also, Android or iOS?

Comment: @user1221780 no,I have no error about it,It is running on iOS simulator

Comment: @Eldelshell I have a try,It worked by used with a button,but I want to let the ListView scroll to the end  at the beginning

Answer (score 20):

There is a workaround, wrap it in a `setTimeout` like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.refs.dateList.scrollToEnd();
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: This is valid, but why

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember where I got this workaround, but i can say I've spent hours struggling with this bug...

Comment: It's bad practice to use setTimeout

Comment: It'll just be because rendering takes time. Use onLayout with a bound method which scrolls to end: e.g.

scrollToBottom() { this.refs.myView.scrollToEnd() }

<List onLayout={this.scrollToBottom}>

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
<ListView
    ref={ ( ref ) => this.scrollView = ref }
    onContentSizeChange={ () => {        
        this.scrollView.scrollToEnd( { animated: false } )
    } } >
</ListView>
```

[document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange)

Answer (score 1):

For functional components, the equivalent is using useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(ref?.current.scrollToEnd());
},[yourArrayData])
```

Note, you don't need to set a duration for the setTimeout, this is because of Macrotasks in JavaScript, https://javascript.info/event-loop if you want to find out more

Comment: Note, with this solution, `yourArrayData` will cause the `useEffect` to call if it changes (if it in state) or has perceived to have changed since React does not run a deep check on objects in a dependency array [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects), this answer is still a viable solution

Comment: Yea I place the yourArrayData in the dependency array because it is equivalent to this other solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46420586/13710770
Use an empty array if you want this other equivalent solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370418/13710770

Answer (score 0):

Rendering takes time so setTimeout() before scrolling to end will work. You can, however, use the onLayout() method.

```
export default MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.scrollToBottom = this.scrollToBottom.bind(this)
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    this.refs.myView.scrollToEnd()
  }

  render() {
    return {
      <ListView
           onLayout={this.scrollToBottom}
           ref='myView'
           ...
      />
   }
 }
```

Note: ListView is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This this worked for me.

```
<Content ref={c => (this.contentComponent = c)}>
....Any code
</Content >
```

This allows you to to use the scrollToPosition(0) function like

```
this.contentComponent._root.scrollToPosition(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's good that the top answer is suggesting using a setTimeout, which sort of goes against React's design.

Imo, the best way to handle this (and what worked for me):

1. Create and set a ref for the scrollable container
2. Have the `onLayout()` method on the List element itself trigger the `.scrollToBottom()` method on the scrollable container ref.

```
const scrollContainer = useRef();

const scrollToEnd = () => {
  chatContainer.current.scrollToEnd();
}

<ScrollView ref={scrollContainer}>
  <FlatList onLayout={scrollToEnd}>
  </Flatlist>
<ScrollView>
```