# [react-native]Is there anyway to know when the flatList's render is completed

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatList view, I want it to scrollToEnd or scrollToIndex when the data has updated(fetch data from server), I do it in comoponentDidUpdate but it doesn't work.Now when the render is completed, the listView always scrolls to top and I cann't see the latest loaded data.So is there a way to capture the event when the render is completed.

**code:**

```
...
fetchData(){
    fetch(url)
    .then((res)=>{
        this.setData({data:[...this.state.data, res.data]})
    })
}
componentDidUpdate(){
    this.refs.listView.scrollToEnd({animated:true})
}
render(){
    return <FlatList ref='listView' data={this.state.data} onEndReached={()=>this.fetchData()}.../>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried concatenate the array while setting data. It will stay in the same scroll position and provide keyExtractor prop for FlatList.

Comment: Take a look at the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313308/react-native-listview-scrolltoend-it-doesnt-work, `onContentSizeChange` seems to be a good solution.

Comment: thanks, @Ashwin Mothilal,you mean [latest data].concat([old data]),I have tried this method but it looks strange.@Prasun, I will try onContentSizeChange.

Comment: Can you see the latest data while scrolling down? If yes, then the FlatList parent or itself may re-render the whole one. By general it won't re-render if you give proper key.